# Sol Balance oddity after buy transaction

Tags: web3.js, transaction, jsonrpc-api, balance, solscan

I am trying to understand the SOL balance changes in transactions.
Solscan shows on the main overview page that 0.001 SOL was used to buy a token
and that is the amount that i passed to the Liquidity.computeAmountOut() function.
[image]

However on the Sol Balance page i see that 0.003 SOL left my account:

[image]

0.02 SOL were added to an account that is related to the token bought.
Unfortunately i did not check my wallet directly to know if 0.001 or 0.003 SOL left it.
So what i don't understand is why the first page and sol balance page have differences
and if i can "trust" the first page as to how many SOL left my account.

0.001 SOL would be the result of -0.003 and +0.002 in that other account.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me better understand this.

EDIT: Since the amount is rather small, the network fee of 0.001 sol might also appear to change the value a lot, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a token that you haven't held before, you need to create a new token account (TA) for that token. Creating this account requires you to deposit a small amount of Sol to it called the rent-exempt amount. This is the extra balance that left your account. (So if you'd buy this token again that amount would not be subtracted). You can read more rent in the Solana Docs [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent).

Other balance changes leaving your wallet are the base tx fee of 5000 lamports and optionally an extra priority fee if you decided to set this.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.

Comment: You're very welcome :)